# Kendo icons not showing after update of Kendo and Angular 14

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, icons

I have a problem with Kendo icons (k-icon k-i-menu etc.) which are now not showing after the latest update of Kendo and Angular to Angular 14.

This is what is showing (just rectangles) and it was working fine until now.  have not changed nothing in the app related to fonts or icons so I don't really know where to search for the problem. I've tried rollback of the Kendo theme to the last version I had before the issue, but it didn't work. I have the issue in 3 different browsers. Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: that is why I use [fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) icons

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that i haven't imported the correct material theme files. Try to add `@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.scss";` to your styles file.